# How to draw real-time updated polyline and display user location based on the location of external input in MAUI Map control?

Tags: android, google-maps, maui

Initially I tried calling the `Polyline.Add(Location)` method directly in the trackpoint update method(MapView is the name of the Map control):

```
private readonly Polyline _track = new()
    {
        StrokeColor = Color.FromArgb("#39C5BB"),
        StrokeWidth = 10,
    };
public TrackDisplayPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
        MapView.MapElements.Add(_track);
    }
private void UpdatePoint(object sender, SensorsService.IntegratedDatasChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code to get currentLocation
        _track.Add(currentLocation);
        Debug.WriteLine($"Add Track:{currentLocation}, Track.Count={_track.Count}");
        //some code
    }
```

But when `_track.Count` reaches about 200, the console outputs the following:

```
[monodroid-gc] 46208 outstanding grefs. performing a full gc!
```

The application becomes unresponsive, and the console continues to output such messages.

Then I tried to re-initialize `PolyLine` each time I update it, by adding track points one by one to `PolyLine` (due to `PolyLine`'s `GeoPath` property being read-only) and then add it to `MapView.MapElements`:

```
private readonly List<Location> _trackPoints = new();
private Polyline Track
    {
        get
        {
            var track = new Polyline
            {
                StrokeWidth = 10,
                StrokeColor = Color.FromArgb("#39c5bb"),
            };
            foreach (var location in _trackPoints)
            {
                track.Add(location);
            }
            return track;
        }
    }

public TrackDisplayPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();                
    }
private void UpdatePoint(object sender, SensorsService.IntegratedDatasChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //some code to get currentLocation
        _trackPoints.Add(currentLocation);
        MapView.MapElements.Clear();
        MapView.MapElements.Add(Track);        
        Debug.WriteLine($"Add Track:{currentLocation}, Track.Count={_trackPoints.Count}");
        //some code
    }
```

The problem was no longer present. However, if there are too many trace points, this can cause performance problems.

And then there's another question. I know that by setting the `IsShowingUser` property of the `Map` control, I can display the current location of the user, but the coordinates of this location are obtained by the map itself. I would like to know if there is a way to pass in the coordinates I have computed to display on the `Map` control as the user's current location.

Comment: Do you want to create a MapSpan object in your map, just like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-mapspan-object) ?